# Camel file component does not move on failure but keeps file locked

Tags: java, file, apache-camel

I created a camel route that reads an xml an puts a message in an ActiveMQ-Queue for every element in xml. All is working fine but the error-handling does not work. Here is the route:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(fileIn)
        .routeId(IN_ROUTE_ID)
        .onCompletion()
            .to(CommonRoutes.ENDPOINT_DIRECT_LOGGING)
        .end()
        .onException(UncategorizedJmsException.class)
            .maximumRedeliveries(maxRetries)
            .backOffMultiplier(multiplier)
            .redeliveryDelay(initialDelay)
        .end()
        .unmarshal(jaxbDataFormat)
        .process(fileProcessor)
        .split(body()).stopOnException().shareUnitOfWork()
        .process(domainWrapProcessor)
        .to(ACTIVE_MQ_OUT + ":queue:" + checkNotNull(queueName))
    .end()
    ;
}
```

And here the configuration of FileEndpoint:

```
public void init(){
    this.setAutoCreate(false);
    this.setFile(new File(checkNotNull(csvFolder)));
    this.setCamelContext(checkNotNull(context));
    this.setAntInclude(ANT_INCLUDE);
    this.setMove(doneFolder);
    this.setMoveFailed(errorFolder);
}
```

The intention is that on every exception the file is moved to moveFailed folder and in case of JMSException (ActiveMQ offline) camel should retry and if finally fails also move to moveFailed.

I have created a unit tests for both cases. here is the test for any exception:

```
@Test
public void testException throws InterruptedException {
    amqMmock.setExpectedMessageCount(3);
    amqMock.whenAnyExchangeReceived((e) -> {
        throw new RuntimeException("");
    });
    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    errorContainsFile(true);
}
```

This test is passing the file is moved into error folder set. But this is not working if i run this route in real (camel blueprint on fuse):

The problem is that on any (not UncategorizedJmsException) exception the file just keeps locked (.camelLock file created). (thanks to stopOnException the desired behavior for JMSExceptions is working) 
So how to get camel to move the file to moveFailed folder on any exception?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, `moveFailed` will only actually move the file to the error-dir if something goes wrong within the file-component itself (at least what I've experienced). This would explain why your file is not moved to the error-dir upon hitting an exception.

What you could try to do is perhaps something like this:

```
.onException(UncategorizedJmsException.class)
    .maximumRedeliveries(maxRetries)
    .backOffMultiplier(multiplier)
    .redeliveryDelay(initialDelay)
    .to(errorFolder)
.end()
```

Here is how I would have set up your route using blueprint with XML rather than Java DSL (well, roughly, just to get the gist of it):

```
<!-- Redelivery Policy -->
<bean id="redeliveryPolicyConfig" class="org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryPolicy">
    <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="${redelivery.max.attempts}" />
    <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="${redelivery.delay.ms}" />
    <property name="logRetryAttempted" value="${redelivery.log.attempts}" />
</bean>

<!-- Error Handler -->
<bean id="errorHandler" class="org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder">
    <property name="deadLetterUri" value="direct:error" />
    <property name="useOriginalMessage" value="true" />
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicyConfig" />
</bean>

<camelContext>
    <route id="IN_ROUTE_ID">
        <from uri="file://{{fileIn}}?move={{doneFolder}}&amp;moveFailed={{errorFolder}}" />
        ...
        <to uri="activemq:queue:{{queueName}}" />
    </route>

    <route id="error-route">
        <from uri="direct:error" />
        <to uri="file://{{errorFolder}}" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: is there any hin why this should work - better than the java way?

Comment: Not really, it is the way we build our contexts and routes and as such the way I'm most familiar with. But I have seen examples where the Java DSL is clunkier and also lacking in functionality in comparison with using XML. One could argue that camel is optimized to the use of XML. Blueprint is also recommended by RedHat when deploying integrations on Karaf in JBoss Fuse if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: sorry but i would never recommend xml because it is not compiled and not type safe you often end up copying parts of xml (very error prone).